# The Facebook like button doesn't appear on my page, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm building a site and I hope to be able to "like" it using Facebook. I've glanced over their SDK, and it seemed pretty straight forward...

I've "made" this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Testing the Facebook like button</h1>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=177127339057410";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yannbane.blogspot.com/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I saved it as "index.html" on my computer. Now, when I try to open it, it just displays  "Testing the Facebook like button" header and continues on loading, and nothing really happens. How come? I'm of course not trying to "like" index.html, but my blog (http://yannbane.blogspot.com/), so I thought there should be no problems with opening it locally...

Comment: I haven't worked with this API, but should  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net begin with the protocol before the "//"? (Like http://)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your head you need to have the opengraph information, facebook requires it for the like button to appear.

the meta tags should look like this

> meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"

Information required is

-og:title
-og:type
-og:image
-og:url
-og:site_name
-fb:admins

you can read more here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: everyone seems to miss that "Step 2" :P

Comment: I also need to include the Javascript SDK? Well, then I'm concerned about the channel file... Can you tell me: if it possible to make like buttons work on local web documents?

Comment: i dont believe you need the javascript SDK, i dont recall adding it, but follow the instructions on fb and it should tell you.  Also did i not answer the question correctly? should have received a correct answer click lol :p :p