# Adding a facebook Like button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I was hoping someone could help me with this:  I tried the facebook like button plugin code generator for HTML5, and I can't get the button to display.  Here is my code (I'm down to trying just the button on the page), with our website replaced with google:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Facebook like button doesn't appear on my page, what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212319/the-facebook-like-button-doesnt-appear-on-my-page-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<fb:like href="http://www.google.com" send="false" width="75" height="20" show_faces="false" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

Comment: thanks - but I get a new error: "Element "fb:like" not allowed as child of element "body" in this context."  Do i need a different doctype?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

Comment: thanks - now this error: "Attribute with the local name "xmlns:fb" is not serializable as XML 1.0."