# how to put"like button" of facebook and twitter in my website?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I want to put "like" button of facebook in my website, I use this

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.google.com.sg/"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

however, it doesn't work if I haven't log into facebook, what't the problem?
and how to implement the same function in twitter?

Comment: you can read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708935/adding-a-facebook-like-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generators for both Twitter and Facebook integrations available for free at the corresponding company's webpage.

However, as you've already written, it will only work when logged in. When you are not logged in it'll display a login page for facebook, see here for a working jsfiddle with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5WAp/

And here for a screenshot of what happens (and SHOULD happen) when I try to like without being logged in to facebook:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Y0N.png

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried the code in the company's webpage, however, there is some problem as I described in the question, would you please give some more information?